# Is it okay to clean your profile?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, rules

I believe many Stack Overflow profiles are consulted by employers, as many profiles are referenced on LinkedIn, and many employers also use Stack Overflow Careers.

Considering this, I think it is a good idea to keep your Stack Overflow profile clean.

I was going to iterate over all my answers/questions to re-format them and add details, and also delete those which actually never had any feedback on post that already have a more detailed answer.

Is it considered okay to iterate over your answers and delete some of them for cleaning purposes?

Comment: Deleting stuff is rate-limited, so if you want to delete a lot it'll take time and I imagine consistently hitting that limit would raise some eyebrows in people looking at the "recently deleted" page of 10k tools, but I think if your overall aim is to improve the quality of your contributions -- that is a good thing.

Comment: If only I had known what the internet was going to turn into 20 years ago, I wouldn't have spent so much time posting so many stupid things on it.

Comment: Great thing I was only 1 year old 20 years ago ;)

Comment: I've run into a rate-limit when fixing links on old answers. I believe it was triggered after the 10th edited post. Nothing stops you from continuing tomorrow.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't believe that has anything to do with editing your own content specifically; if you're editing anything too fast, you'll get rate-limited. That happens to me all of the time when I'm fixing up posts to burninate tags.

Comment: You're always welcome to review and improve content on Stack Exchange. But generally, removing useful stuff is frowned upon.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

We have users do this all the time; where it becomes an issue is when it appears the user is doing it simply to "take their ball and go home". If that's ever your intent on answers that have been upvoted, your best bet is to ask us to disassociate that post from your profile.

We do get flagged when you start deleting your own content, so depending on the nature of the deletions/content, you may or may not have a moderator send you a message. I typically don't.

Comment: there are reasons to remove old answers beyond "take your ball and go home": preserving them when they are attached to "at-risk" questions for instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but english is not my main language. Would you please confirm that by "take their ball and go home" you mean for example a user that would post on high-voted questions just to get votes, then delete if the answer get no feedback/downvotes ?

Comment: @Plutonix I am also not sure what you mean by "at-risk" questions ?

Comment: @Plutonix How does removing an answer preserve it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard "Take their ball and go home" means a user is trying to quit SO in a rage and delete all of the answers they posted on their way out. Cleaning up is fine. Destroying useful content is not.

Comment: "take [my] ball and go home" is a metaphor that means a user is (sometimes) selfishly quitting something because they're unhappy about the outcome.  Also known as 'ragequitting', in the parlance of our times.  In this case, it'd refer to the act of deleting good content because you're unhappy with [something] involving Stack Overflow/Exchange.

Comment: Right, so to resume all this, as long as my intents are good, there is nothing wrong with deleting answers ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Part of it has to do with the content itself. No one cares if you throw trash away. Everyone cares if you throw away a working TV, or an Apple Watch, or a working Apple TV .

Comment: @Jean-François Yes, if you're just trying to clean up answers that weren't that useful, nobody will bother you.

Comment: Great, now just to understand even more, suppose I consider something as a Hyundai, but a moderator consider it as a Lamborghini, in the worse case I will only be notified to un-delete the answer ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard It's a waste to throw away both hyundais and lambos; stick to the throwing away trash. In all seriousness, be extra careful once you're dealing with content that has upvotes. Those typically denote quality (vs. zero-voted items).

Comment: Not if we recycle them ;)... Thanks a lot to both of you for a fast answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: what's concerned me about dissociating answers from users is that any comments below them that are directed toward the user immediately give away his/her identity. Do you guys address that somehow?